How to pass data to some application where the application url is rendered in an iframe and that iframe is rendered in chrome extension
I have build a chrome extension and inside the chrome extension i created an iframe and in src field of iframe i pasted my application url. so whenever user open the extension it will open my application, But the issue is i want to store the user data(credentials, token) in such a way that if user open the extension in other pages/tabs the data(credentials, token) should be accessible, in my application im using localStorage to store the user credentials, but when user switches to other tabs, there is no information i localStorage
Example: User opened a coding platform leetcode and logged in my applition by opening extension, but when user switched to other tab, GFG then user is again asked to login
I want to store the user credentials such a way that it will only ask user once and the data should be accessible to different tabs
I tried by emitting an event through the extension background.js and i also added eventListner in my application but not able to receive the data which was sent through extension
content.js
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        const {href} = window.location
        if(event.data.action === 'token-updated'){
            console.log("token updated", event.data.token)
            chrome.storage.local.set({ token: event.data.token }).then(() => {
                console.log("Value is set", event.data.token);
            });
    
            chrome.storage.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                console.log("Value is " + result.token);
            });
        } else if (event.data.action === 'requestData') {
            const key = event.data.key;
    
            // Get the requested data from Chrome storage
            chrome.storage.local.get([key], (result) => {
                const data = result[key];
    
                // Send the data back to the iframe
                event.source.postMessage({ action: 'responseData', data: data }, event.origin);
            });
        }
    });

manifest.json
    {
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "name": "Api Analyzer",
        "description": "Analyzes all ypu API's and give optimization of api tips",
        "author": "Chary",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/logo16.png",
                "48": "images/logo48.png",
                "128": "images/logo128.png"
        }
    },
        "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "declarativeContent"
    ],
        "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "all_frames":true
        }
    ],
        "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
        "icons": {
        "16": "images/logo16.png",
            "48": "images/logo48.png",
            "128": "images/logo128.png"
    },
        "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": [
            "images/*.png"
        ],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "extension_ids": []
    }]
    }

background.js
    chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        console.log("ckicked")
    });
    
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request, sender, sendResponse)
        if (request.action === 'requestData') {
            sendResponse({data: { value: "my value"});
        }
    });


Each domain has its own local storage. If you want to pass data between domains, you should put it in the URL of the iframe src.


You correctly use chrome.storage, but you didn't show your app's code that uses window.postMessage and listens to the response. 2) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. 3) There's no need for the background script in the example you've shown, but you can actually use it instead of content.js via externally_connectable messages directly from your app.

